# Why does VLC media player pop up "YOU JUST UNPLUGGED A DEVICE"?

Tags: windows-7, audio, vlc-media-player, windows-media-player

When I try to play music MP3 files with VLC media player or with Windows media player, a notification always pops up saying "YOU JUST UNPLUGGED A MEDIA DEVICE" and disturbs the music.

What should I do to stop this? I'm using Windows 7 64 bit with Realtech HD auto manager.

Answer (score 1):

It's a hardware issue. What you can do is turn down the sound/notification in settings.

RightClick on Desktop > Personalize > Sounds > (In the "Program Events Box" select Device Connect and Device Disconnect and below them in the drop down menu select none for sounds)

[Read here for more info](http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/167954-how-turn-off-visual-sound-notifications.html)

Comment: This is a workaround not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that one of your external devices has bad connection.

Here is a method to try:

1. Play a local file with VLC.
2. Unplug all external devices, and see if the notification still appears.
3. If step 2 returns true, I cannot understand this problem. Else, go to step 4.
4. Plug in external devices one by one, until the notification appears again. The last device being plugged in is the source of the problem.